On Android getting 3 error strange error after upgrade expo from 49 to 50

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method android() for arguments [KotlinExpoModulesCorePlugin$_apply_closure4@710349e1] on project ':expo-permissions' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

I tried to look up this 3 issues on Expo github as well but there is no-one reported this issue. I have removing node modules and invalidated cache and restart. if anyone face this issue please help. Thanks in advanceI have encountered three issues and have attempted to locate them on the Expo GitHub repository, but there are no reported instances of these issues. I have taken steps to troubleshoot the issues, including removing node modules, invalidating the cache, and restarting the system. If anyone has encountered similar issues, I would appreciate your assistance.
